# Understanding formula for max number of data sortable in two passes with merge sort

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I learned the merge sort algorithm for external sorting and I am trying to form some intuition for the formula.

Suppose we have a large amount of books (in a library disk), say $N$ books, and we wish to have them sorted (say, by author's lastname). We can only sort books once we've carried them to our table which can hold $B$ books.

So we divide the stack of $N$ books into $N/B$ substacks.
Then merge $(B-1)$ substacks at each "pass" until we have only 1 large stack remaining.

Why does this imply that the maximum $N$ that can be sorted in two passes = $B(B-1)$? I just don't see it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to define the operation and what you mean by passes more carefully.  One operation I can imagine is to bring $B$ books to the table and sort them.  Take them back to the disk with some dividers showing this group of books.  Sort each group of $B$ books that way.  Now take the first book of each group to the table.  Find the first one of the group and output it.  Replace it on the table with the next book of its group.  This will handle $B^2$ books in what looks to me like two passes.  I must be violating some rule, but don't see what it is.